# How to copy contents of one datablock to another on clicking checkbox in Oracle Forms Builder?

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have made two data blocks --> Present Address and Permanent Address. Both are database items. 
Now I have made a non-database item checkbox, clicking on which should copy the contents of Present address into Permanent Address.
I have made a  'WHEN-CHECKBOX-CHANGED' trigger on 'check' data block What code should I write in the trigger?

Answer (score -1):

You can use built-in function:

```
 DUPLICATE_RECORD;
```

Comment: `DUPLICATE_RECORD` would duplicate the record in the same block.  OP is requesting that the data be copied to another block.